# Помогите разобраться с аутентификацией Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, auth

Суть проблемы такова. Есть база с таблицей users. Поле password хранит в себе пароль, получить который можно выполнив следующий запрос:

`'SELECT DECODE('some_user_password','some_secret_key') AS password FROM users WHERE id = 'test'';`

Секрет для функции `DECODE()` мне известен (взял из конфигов рабочего проекта, который написан на перле и не мной).

Добавляются данные в эту таблицу с и использованием функции `ENCODE('some_user_password','some_secret_key')` в самом sql-запросе. На сколько я смог понять из perl-кода это единственный метод хеширования используемый данным приложением.

Что можно сделать,чтобы  работал стандартный метод аутентификации Laravel (изменять базу не вариант). Как можно изменить стандартный метод хеширования пароля в Laravel?

Comment: Чтобы понять **как** изменить метод хеширования пароля в Laravel, нужно понять **каким** методом хеширует пароль perl-функция `DECODE` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы вы смогли авторизоваться через Laravel к вашей базе - нужно создать свой драйвер для авторизации в котором переопределить метод который проверяет пароли или создать свой хэшер, я же подскажу по первому варианту.

Этапов не мало, так что покажу сразу на примере:

1) Для начала нужно создать свой Provider, который наследуется от `EloquentUserProvider` и переопределяем в нем метод `validateCredentials`:

```
namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider;

class CustomUserProvider extends EloquentUserProvider
{
    /**
     * Validate a user against the given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  array  $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
}
```

Это оригинальный метод, меняете в нём логику проверки на свою, главное чтобы в итоге на выходе было `bool` значение.
В переменной `$plain` - пароль который ввел пользователь на форме входа.

2) Теперь скажем фреймворку что работа с пользователями будет происходить через наш новый провайдер. Для этого изменим пару строк в `config/auth.php`:

```
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'custom',
    'model' => App\Entities\User::class //Обратите внимание на путь к модели, у меня он не стандартный
],
```

3) Но прежде чем проверять необходимо объявить провайдер. Для этого указываем в `AuthServiceProvider` в методе `boot` следующее:

```
\Auth::provider('custom', function ($app, array $config) {
    return new CustomUserProvider($app['hash'], $config['model']);
});
```

4) Теперь можно проверить авторизацию, она будет работать через новый провайдер.

P.S. Какие то проблемы с форматированием кода в ответе, но вроде бы получилось.

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало, стоило лишь увидеть достойно объяснение. Занимаюсь изучением этого фреймворка меньше недели)

Comment: @SWic меньше недели и уже такие задачи)

Comment: появились такие задачи по работе. вот и решил уже учиться нормально, не делать на скору руку по готовым решениям из сети на php